React-player showing static image of video on mobile screen, but works fine on desktop
I am using React-player for showing a short local video in webm format. it was working fine to begin with, but suddenly when i check my website on mobile screen it is just a static image of the video with a black background.
how it looks like on mobile
website: https://techhype.no/
For desktop the video is running like normal.
I tried updating the react-player to last version. I tried import the video and have the video in the public folder and refrence it directly. Still same issue.
Here is the code:
import React from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import Techvideo from "videos/animation-video.webm";

const PhoneAnimation = () => {
  return (
    <div className="phone-grapich">
      <ReactPlayer
        url={Techvideo}
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        loop
        muted
        playing
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PhoneAnimation;

